# Proof of the Farey sequence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, farey-sequences

How would I go about proving that the Farey sequence contains all possible numbers? I'm new to number theory, so from observation the sequence looks to have all fractions. But I cannot figure out a proof that any fraction can be created with the fact that numbers in the sequence. I am using the same Farey method where you take fractions $m/n$ and $p/q$ and add them to have $\frac{m+p}{n+q}$

Comment: What definition of the Farey sequence are you using? The usual definition, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence), includes all rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ as a trivial consequence of the definition.

Comment: Sorry. I have fixed the link. To expand: the *definition* of the Farey sequence is about listing the rational numbers by increasing denominators. The algorithm for constructing that listing using mediants is an interesting consequence of that definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we construct a list of sequences of rational numbers (and a fake rational number number $\frac10$ which we think of as $+\infty$) by

- starting with the sequence $\frac01, \frac10$;
- taking the previous sequence, and inserting $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ between every pair of consecutive terms $\frac ab$, $\frac cd$.

Then you want to show that every positive rational number $\frac pq > 0$ will appear eventually.

To do this, we'll need two facts:

**Fact 1.** The fractions in each sequence appear in increasing order.

To show this, check that if $\frac ab < \frac cd$, then $\frac ab < \frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac cd$, so the order property is maintained as we go from each sequence to the next.

**Fact 2.** Consecutive fractions $\frac ab, \frac cd$ in any sequence satisfy $\frac cd - \frac ab = \frac1{bd}$.

To show this, check that if it's true, then $\frac{a+c}{b+d} - \frac ab = \frac1{b(b+d)}$ and $\frac cd - \frac{a+c}{b+d} = \frac1{(b+d)d}$, so this property is also preserved as we go from each sequence to the next.

---

Now, let's prove that every fraction $\frac pq$ will always be found.

Initially, $\frac pq$ is somewhere between $\frac01$ and $\frac10$. At each step, we'll keep track of the two consecutive terms $\frac ab , \frac cd$ such that $\frac ab < \frac pq < \frac cd$.

As long as this is true, we have
$$
   \frac1{bd} = \frac cd - \frac ab = \left(\frac cd - \frac pq\right) + \left(\frac pq - \frac ab\right) \ge \frac1{dq} + \frac1{qb},
$$
and by multiplying through by $bdq$, we get $q \ge b+d$. So the sum of the denominators of the fractions bracketing $\frac pq$ can never exceed $q$.

Every time we go from a sequence to the next sequence and insert $\frac{a+b}{c+d}$ between $\frac ab$ and $\frac cd$, either $\frac{a+b}{c+d} = \frac pq$ (and we are done), or $\frac ab < \frac pq < \frac{a+b}{c+d}$ (and we have our next two consecutive fractions between which $\frac pq$ must lie), or $\frac {a+b}{c+d} < \frac pq < \frac cd$ (and we have our next two consecutive fractions between which $\frac pq$ must lie).

The sum of the denominators of the fractions bracketing $\frac pq$ always keeps increasing, but it can't exceed $q$, so there can be only finitely many iterations before we stop.