# How best to select $d$ from $[d_1, d_2]$ so $n/d$ is closest to $p/q$

Tags: number-theory, approximation, fractions

An answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68145730/1089161) asked how to approximate $pi$ with denominators in a certain range (where the minimum denominator is not necessarily 1). This is *almost* solved by the continued-fraction approach, but the requirement that the denominator not be smaller than a certain value is the challenge. I am able to suggest a method of not testing every denominator in the range, by finding the range of numerators that are candidates given the range of candidates.

e.g. what is the best approximation of $5/41$ with a fraction having denominator in range $[170, 200]$? We can find that numerators will have to be in the range $[21, 24]$ which is smaller than the denominator range. These numerators correspond to candidates $21/172, 22/180, 23/189, 24/197$ where $24/197$ is closest to $5/41$. When ordered by value instead of numerator, these candidates are $23/189, 24/197, 21/172, 22/180$ and it is clear that they are ordered by neither numerator nor denominator.

It seems like one must simply test each candidate to find the closest approximation. Is there a better way?

In a given interval $[a/D, (a+1)/D]$, is there a way to know in what order numerators of fractions with denominators $d_i$ with $d <= d_i < D$ will appear? If $a = 1$ and $D/d < 2$ we know the order since all numerators will be 1 in the interval, e.g. if $d=170$ and $D=200$ then $1/200 < 1/119 < ... 1/170 < 2/200$. But when $a=24$ then numerators $18-25$ appear on fractions between $24/200$ and $25/200$ in this order (with the stars around the value that corresponded to the numerator of the best approximation):
$$[18, 21, 24, 22, 19, 
23, 20, 24, 21, 22, 
19, 23, 20, 24, 21, 
22, 23, 19, *24*, 20,
21, 22, 23, 24, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
24, 19, 20, 21, 22,
23, 24, 19, 20, 21, 
22, 23, 24, 25]$$

Comment: Farey sequence may be useful for you.
[Farey sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060893/proof-of-the-farey-sequence)

Comment: That is what I meant with the "almost" qualification for continued fraction. You can use the Farey method when the initial fraction has a denominator larger than interest but the result will be the closest fraction with denominator smaller than the desired limit. But if the denominator must be greater than some value and if the Farey result is smaller then you don't want the best solution. Similarly (as shown with 5/41) the answer cannot be approached with the Farey method. All you will know is that the answer lies between the values of the two children in the Stern-Brocot table.